# Package with Rcpp code won't build on windows

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm not sure what I've done but I can't seem to get this package to build while it contains Rcpp code. I've installed MinGW appropriately (I think) and added it to my path (I think).

Full disclosure, I hardly ever work on windows.

When I try to build and reload, this is the error I get:

```
Warning: running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.4RE/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.4RE/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="packagename.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="RcppExports.o somefunC.o somefunC.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'packagename'
```

Some basic things to check:

```
library(devtools)
find_rtools() # TRUE
has_devel()

"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.4RE/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ  \
  --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD SHLIB foo.c 

gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.4RE/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c foo.c -o foo.o
gcc -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o foo.dll tmp.def foo.o -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.4RE/bin/x64 -lR
[1] TRUE
```

The system path variable on the computer:

%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin

A couple of notes:

- In my descrition file I import Rcpp, and I added the link LinkingTo: Rcpp
- In my package documentation I have the `@useDynLib packagename` directive
- In my package I also have  `@importFrom Rcpp evalCpp`

Update:

- When I remove the src directory, the package does build.
- `evalCpp("2+2")` works as expected
- Now that RBuildTools is on the path, I see a "pure virtual method" showing up when I restart R.
- I also get a new error message c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++; not found. This is interesting because Rtools is installed in a folder (that I did not choose) called RBuildTools and is in the path.

Comment: Did you install Rtools, or just MinGW? The former is required, and the locations of Rtools and R should be the first thing on your path. This is described in the appendix of the R Installation and Administration manual.

Comment: Try `library(Rcpp); evalCpp("2+2")` -- if that does not work you have fundamental issues on your box.  Also try a simple package on win-builder to rule out the packaging by using a known working machine and setup.

Comment: And of course: Look at the now over 750 packages on CRAN using Rcpp. Those too make good test cases as you can also see which ones have Windows builds.

Comment: I'm reinstalling RTools (was not on path, now is), I also installed MinGW (was on path, still is). evalCpp("2+2") worked for me. Looks like it's looking for RTools in C:/Rtools/ but on this system it's installed in C:/RBuildTools/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I don't know what specific step led to my solution (or perhaps a combination) there was definitely something awry with the RTools install on this system.

- Updated to newer R version
- Installed packages again
- Intalled MingW
- Added MingW to path
- Reinstalled Rtools at C:/Rtools (it was at RBuildTools on this machine)
- Removed references in path to RBuildTools/, changed them to Rtools/

I suspect that it was the non-standard location of Rtools that was causing the problem. But I don't know enough about the windows version to speculate.

Comment: I'd just delete the question.  There is nothing here other than a log of you stating that your system was confused, is no longer confused and you're unsure of how it got into either state.

Comment: Now that I've answered it I can't delete it directly. But anyways, it's probably good for someone else to see if they ever have the same problem. If you want to initiate a close vote I'll second it.

Comment: Done -- "cannot be reproduced" suits it quite well.   (And don't get me wrong: I know where you are coming from. I too find Windows very frustrating and difficult to work with. That said, when the tools are lined up, it works.  And this question just didn't really help in lining things up ....)

Comment: Agreed. I'm not sure why, but someone decided to install `Rtools` to `RBuildTools` and there was some kind of hard coding in the system that makes it look for `Rtools`. I suppose we could recreate it that way, but I'm too lazy to try.